# how to get characters of an NSString?

Tags: iphone

NSString *data=@"123456789";
here i need first 3 characters into one string and next 2 characters into another string and next 4 characters into another string how can i get this guide me

thanks for advance

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should learn to read the doc: [substringWithRange:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringWithRange%3a)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use substringWithRange. Check this example:

```
NSString *substring = [aString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(15, 5)];
```

It does start with the 15th character and it includes the next 5 characters.

*Like mentioned before please try to investigate some minutes googling.. I'm sure you would have found a solution extreemely fast...*